# Will I be banned if I use the same account on 2 devices? (Not simultaneously)

Tags: pokemon-go

I have 2 devices with Pokemon Go installed. I would like to know if I alternate the same account between the two (if I need to use one of them for something else or the battery unloads), I run the risk of having the account banned?

Comment: The chance of getting banned will be pretty high, if you have both devices in a different location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Niantic (sensibly) does not tell us what they use to determine whether to ban people, it is not *generally* a problem to use the same account from two devices; it's not an uncommon thing, for example, to use it on one phone and one tablet.

I've used it on two different phones several times before, in addition to having switched to an iPhone 7 a few months ago (several months into my gameplay) and having to use both the old phone and the new one for a week or so while the new phone's wrinkles were ironed out.

Note that *sharing* accounts is against ToS (i.e., you and your significant other having one account between the two of you), but it doesn't look like they've made much effort to ban that.  Also note that there are some reports of *three* devices from the same IP causing a ban, but not two.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Trainer's Guide](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/221993967-Pok%C3%A9mon-GO-Trainer-guidelines), Niantic defines cheating somewhat vaguely as,

> Methods of cheating, unfortunately, are limited only by cheaters’
>   imaginations, but include at a minimum the following: using modified
>   or unofficial software; playing with multiple accounts (one account
>   per player, please); sharing accounts; using tools or techniques to
>   alter or falsify your location; or selling/trading accounts.

Although there is more in the terms of service, nothing in this or the TOS suggests using one account on multiple devices would in and of itself be considered cheating.  I have used the same account on a phone and a WiFi only tablet since the start of the game with no problems from Niantic.

My phone gets the "I am not a robot" screens once and awhile no matter if the tablet is used or not. Most often after leaving the app running all night. Once I pass the visual Captcha test the game accepts me with no problems.